# Visual c++ 2005 'Ports' : is not a member of 'System::IO'

Tags: .net, serial-port, managed-c++

I'm trying to use SerialPort with Microsoft Visual Studio 2005, .Net Framework 2 installed, but I can't compile the simple example below:

```
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
SetParameters(1, 9600, 8, System::IO::Ports::Parity::Even, 300);
```

because 'Ports' : is not a member of 'System::IO', I have activated Common Language Runtime Support (/clr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add #using < System.dll > in source code